# How to get the mouse clicking position on an obj file loaded from OBJLoader?

Tags: three.js, webgl

I loaded the model using OBJLoader, here is the code for loading the obj file:

```
        var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
        loader.load('obj/teeth/teeth4_5.obj', function(object) {
            model = object;
            scene.add( model );
            objects.push( model );
        });
```

And I'm trying to use raycaster to find the intersection. I implemented my code from the canvas_interactive_cubes example (http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/canvas_interactive_cubes.html) in three.js. Here is the code to find the intersection:

```
    function onDocumentMouseDown( event ){
        event.preventDefault();
        var mouseX = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth)*2-1;
        var mouseY = -(event.clientY /window.innerHeight)*2+1;
        var vector = new THREE.Vector3( mouseX, mouseY, 0.5 );
        projector.unprojectVector( vector, camera );
        var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster( camera.position, vector.sub( camera.position ).normalize() );
        var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children );
        console.log( intersects[0].point);
    }
```

Unfortunately I'm not able to get the x,y,z coordinates of the intersection, no matter where I clicked, it always showed "TypeError: intersects[0] is undefined".

I'm getting stuck here for several days. Can someone tell me a way to get the intersection on a loaded obj file? I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try adding the recursive flag like so:

```
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( objects, true );
```

three.js r.58

Comment: WOW, it works... that's so easy. Seems like I asked a silly question. And it takes long to find a intersection on a large obj file. Thanks a lot for your answer!!

Comment: I’ve spent 2 hours on this. Add `,true` and it works. I've never seen it on several examples that i studied. Thanks !