# Raycaster doesn't detect intersection with .gltf object

Tags: javascript, three.js, gltf

If I use raycaster in this way to detect the intersection of the mouse with a cube it works just fine !

```
  raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera)
  const intersects = raycaster.intersectObject(cubeMesh)
  if(intersects.length > 0)
  console.log('intersecting')
```

and after this I have a .gltf object which is positioned exactly as the `cubeMesh` and I do check if it is loaded first and all this is taking place in an "update" function (every frame) but the interseciton with the .gltf is not detected:

```
const Update = () => {

  renderer.render(scene, camera)

  raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera)
  
  if(gltfObj){
    const intersects = raycaster.intersectObject(gltfObj)
    if(intersects.length > 0)
    console.log('intersecting')
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(Update);
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16160263/1461008

Answer (score 0):

Soled:
I changed this line and it worked:

```
const intersects = raycaster.intersectObject(gltfObject, true)
```